# why there is not enough space on my desktop while there is enogh space on my disk c?

Tags: windows-8.1

I am trying to transfer a movie from disk d to desktop, which I assume is in  disk c.( I have only these two disks.) There is 16.6 g out of 98.1 g on c disk, but when I am trying to copy the 6g movie to the desktop, the system pop up a dialog saying there is not enough space to transfer.
my system is win 8.1, lenovo yoga 11s.
thanks in adnvance

Comment: Do you have lots of icons on your desktop?

Comment: I guess, 4 columns.

Comment: Is it possible the filename and path is really long? (more than 255 chars)

Comment: chars is character,,right? it is roughly 50 characters

Comment: You indicate you have 2 disks.  How much space do you have free on the other disk?

Comment: none, that is why I want to move it to disk c

Comment: Instead of putting the video on the Desktop, try putting it in the Documents/Video folder. Although I cannot see why Microsoft would limit what goes on the Desktop.

Comment: @LDC3, YES, That works. it is  kinda strange.

Comment: @jxhyc Can you put a shortcut to the video on the desktop?